# mysql select one record from cerain categories, for rest categories this rule not affected

Tags: php, mysql, select

Simplified view of issue.

Select only One record from category 2 and 3. From another categories any count allowed. 

`id  categoryid  data
1       2       somedata 
2       2       somedata
3       2       somedata
4       3       somedata
5       3       somedata
6       4       somedata
7       4       somedata
8       5       somedata
9       5       somedata
10      6       somedata
11      6       somedata
12      6       somedata
13      7       somedata
14      7       somedata
15      8       somedata`

`select * from table order by RAND() limit 10`

Requirement is one query. Maybe stored procedure.

Expected result:

`id  categoryid  data
8       5       somedata
6       4       somedata
14      7       somedata
9       5       somedata
1       2       somedata  <---categoryid=2. only one record
12      6       somedata
4       3       somedata  <---categoryid=3. only one record 
13      7       somedata
7       4       somedata
15      8       somedata`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly using variables to come up with a sequence number:-

```
SELECT id, categoryid, data
FROM
(
    SELECT id, categoryid, data, @seq:=IF(@prev_cat = categoryid, @seq + 1, 1) AS CatSeq, @prev_cat = categoryid
    FROM someTable
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq:=0, @prev_cat:=0) Sub1
    ORDER BY category_id, id
)
WHERE (categoryid IN (2,3) AND CatSeq = 1)
OR categoryid NOT IN (2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
GROUP BY categoryid
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want single row for category 2 and 3 but all rows for other categories, so you can Use below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE categoryid IN (2,3)
GROUP BY categoryid
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE categoryid NOT IN (2,3);
```

If you want random one value then you can use below:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE categoryid IN (2,3)
GROUP BY categoryid
ORDER BY RAND()
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE categoryid NOT IN (2,3);
```